# Ich gebe Dir eine Hand beim Deutschlernen vs. Ich helfe Dir beim Deutschlernen

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Würde es Sinn ergeben, wenn man *Ich gebe dir eine Hand beim Deutschlernen* sagt?

```
Wäre dieser Satz umgangssprachlich?
```

Comment: Das ist eine 1:1 Übersetzung von *I'll give/lend you a hand ...*. Diese Formulierung gibt es im Deutschen nicht. Wir sagen *Ich helfe Dir bei...* oder *Ich gehe Dir zur Hand bei...*, wobei Letzteres wirklich eine körperliche/handwerkliche Tätigkeit voraussetzt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Redewendung lautet „[jemandem zur Hand *gehen*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemandem_zur_Hand_gehen)“.

Aber auch „Ich gehe dir zur Hand beim Deutschlernen“ klingt erzwungen und unnatürlich.

Comment: Jemandem geht man nur zur Hand, wenn es um die Erledigung einer (meistens körperlicher) Aufgabe geht. Und es steckt IMO ein bisschen ein Rangunterschied drin: Wenn der Lehrling das erste Mal ein Rohr montieren darf und der Meister hilft ihm dabei, dann würde man nicht sagen "zur Hand gehen". Umgekehrt schon.

Answer (score 0):

"Ich gebe dir eine Hand beim Deutschlernen" sagt kein Mensch.